# In MS Access while making query how can i map time interval in hours

Tags: ms-access

I am working on data in MS Access so let me tell you the whole scenario. i have made a macro which collates all CSV files into TABLE called "Collate" then i have imported 3 Excels into 3 different tables: 1st is Employee details 2nd is Dispositions and 3rd is time Interval.

What i want is i have made query and used left join method but now i want is to map Time interval in query where i have divided Date and Time separate into two using (Calling Time: Format[[Collate]![Call Time],"HH:MM:SS AM/PM")) which was taken from table "Collate" but in query what i want is time interval for an example if the time is 8:00:01 AM then interval is 8:00 AM or if it is 8:45:01 AM then also it will be 8:00 AM interval so basically i have made Excel and uploaded the interval in 3rd table like i said above. So how can i map interval in query i have derived the Time using formula using build so now how can i get time interval next to it
[image]

Comment: Why does DispositionCode link to two fields in Collate? Extract hour portion with: `Hour([Call Time])`. It will return a value from 0 to 23. Or `Format([Call Time], "HH AM/PM")`. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: COllate consist of raw file in CSV format in which there is calling date and time together so what i did is seperated it in query but the thing is i have another table called interval so how can i map that interval in query it is giving error

Comment: about linking the dispositioncode in collate two time is in collate there is disposition code which is primary so if that is blank then we take system disposition in excel formula will look like (=if(Dispositioncode ="",system disposition,dispositioncode)) so in access we can do that in query i guess so that is did but i cannot add time interval like(8:00 AM, 9:00 AM, 10:00 AM etc....) and status from disposition in query to get "COnnect" or "No Connect"

Comment: That linking makes no sense. If two fields need to link to same table then that table must be included in query twice. Most likely field will be Null not empty string when 'blank'. I never allow empty string in field. You have not provided requested info. Build query that calculates extracted value then build another query joining that query to Interval table.